# Parse Java code with JavaParser and find the statement type of parent nodes

Tags: java, nodes, statements, javaparser

I have made a small program that uses *JavaParser* [[1]](https://javaparser.org/) to parse Java code and identify the types of statements that appear in the code. This has been implemented successfully. What I want to do next, and is a bit tricky, is to find the parent node for an `if-statement`, and check whether the first statement of the parent node is a `while-loop`. After confirming that the above statement is true, I also want to find if this `if-statement` is the last child of the parent node.

Following you can find an example of the above description:

```
void example() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    while (y < 3) {
        while (x < 4) {
            x++;                
        }
        if (y < 5) {
            y++;  
        }
    }
    x = 0;
}
```

The main question I have with parsing the above code, is how to obtain that the parent node of `if (y < 5 )` is a `while-loop` (`while (y < 3)`) and secondly, which might be even trickier, is how to identify that the `if-statement` of this example is the last statement before we skip back to the parent `loop`. There is also `y++;` inside the `if` but it might be skipped if the condition of the `if` is not true, so I do not want to consider it as the last child of the parent node. I believe what I should do is to check for the last "neighbour"? What I mean by neighbour is the relationship between the second `while` and the `if` of this example, i.e. they are at the same level.

My thoughts so far implemented:

```
//find if the if-statement has a parent node
if (currIf.getParentNode().isPresent()) {
    //find if the parent Node is a While loop
    Optional<Node> parent = currIf.getParentNode();
    parent.get().getBegin();
}
```

With the above code I am able to check if the `if-statement` has a parent node and I can find the location of the first `while` but I do not know how to confirm that it is a `while statement` and also implement the second described part.

UPDATE:

I managed to find how to check if the parent is a `while-loop` and currently trying to find a solution on how to identify that the `if-statement` is the last `statement` of its level (or hierarchy if you prefer).

```
Optional<WhileStmt> ifParent = currIf.findAncestor(WhileStmt.class);
//find if the if-statement has a parent node
if (ifParent.isPresent()) {
//find if the parent Node is a While loop
        Optional<Node> sameNode = ifParent.get().findFirst(Node.class, n -> n == currIf);
        if (sameNode.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(sameNode);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update could give you the wrong result if I am understanding it correctly. Yes, your solution will work if a `WhileStmt` is the parent, but it also could give you a `WhileStmt` a bit further up the tree.

Why can't  you do something like the following?

```
 boolean parentIsWhileLoop = ifStmtNode.getParent() instanceof WhileStmt;
```

For determining if the `ifStmt` is the last node, you could do

```
 Node ifStmtParent = ifStmt.getParent();
 List<Node> ifStmtSibilings = ifStmtParent.getChildNodes();
 Node lastNode = ifStmtSiblings.get(ifStmtSiblings.size() - 1);
 boolean ifStmtIsLast = lastNode == ifStmt;
```